# Howto refactor for loop with Service call into Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

how would you refactor this code into Streams?

```
for (ConditionEntity conditionEntity : dbData.getContent()) {
    AdminCondition adminCondition = 
            dataEntityMapper.conditionEntitytoModel(conditionEntity);

    this.myService.addBasicInterest(adminCondition); // <=== this is my Problem
    conditionList.add(adminCondition);
}
```

I've this so far:

```
dbData.getContent().stream()
    .map(conditionEntity -> dataEntityMapper.conditionEntitytoModel(conditionEntity))
    .collect(conditionList);
```

Thx for help!

Comment: Create a separate method, send the conditionEntity make the action with the service return conditionEntity to the map of stream and collect the resut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer the following solution:

```
List<ConditionEntity> conditions = dbData.getContent().stream()
        .map(dataEntityMapper::conditionEntitytoModel)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

conditions.forEach(this::addBasicInterest);
```

Comment: Nice one, but generaly peek is used for debuging I would call the service in the method and return the data Object to the map

Comment: I don't think you need that extra method. You can just do `dataEntityMapper::conditionEntitytoModel`.

Comment: its probably about time we call `peek(myService::addBasicInterest)` an anti-pattern and burn that in all minds

Comment: @Eugene True. Would be better to just do `myService.addBasicInterests(conditions)` at the end instead.

Comment: I have edited my answer to not use `peek` anymore. I aggree with @Eugene that it should not be used in that context.

Comment: Thx, i prefer this. Good point YCF_L, i have looked in the comment .. you are right peek exsits for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<AdminCondition > conditionList = new ArrayList<>();

dbData.getContent()
      .stream()
      .map(conditionEntity -> dataEntityMapper.conditionEntitytoModel(conditionEntity))
      .forEach(adminCondition  -> {
            this.myService.addBasicInterest(adminCondition);
            conditionList.add(adminCondition);
                   });
```

Comment: This looks nice ... but conditionList has to be final  :(

Comment: Oh .. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like below.

```
dbData.getContent().stream()
  .map(conditionEntity -> {
      AdminCondition adminCondition = dataEntityMapper.conditionEntitytoModel(conditionEntity);
      this.myService.addBasicInterest(adminCondition);
  }) 
.collect(conditionList);
```

Comment: map took a Function which mean it should return something

Comment: Thx, I had the variant already. But how can I justify that this is better and more legible than for loop

Comment: It should return adminCondition. It is very hard to say which is more readable. I think one way to make it more readable would be to rename conditionLIst to adminConditionList just so that we know that it is a list of adminConditions.  I personally find non-stream versions more readable sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely I would put this into two separate Statements.

```java
dbData.getContent().stream()
    .map(conditionEntity -> dataEntityMapper.conditionEntitytoModel(conditionEntity))
    .collect(conditionList);

conditionList.forEach(adminCondition -> this.myService.addBasicInterest(adminCondition))
```